# Read container names of an Azure blob in Data Factory V2

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

My Data Factory V2 pipeline imports CSV files from an Azure blob.

Is there any way in Data Factory V2 to automatically read the names of the containers of which the CSV files are taken from? I search to hand them over to a Microsoft SQL Server and/or save them in the streamed CSV data itself.

Comment: When you say `folders`, you mean `containers` ?

Comment: There is no such thing as a folder in blob storage. Only containers.

Comment: Oh sure, thanks guys :)

Comment: @MichelleTurner Does my answer helps you?

Comment: @MichelleTurner Does my answer helps you?

Answer (score 1):

Just as which is mentioned in the comments, there is no such thing named folder in Azure Blob Storage. You can only get names of container.

Based on the [Azure Data Factory REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/datasets/get#examples), you can get the `folderPath` from the `dataset` response body.

sample :

```
{
  "id": "/subscriptions/12345678-1234-1234-12345678abc/resourceGroups/exampleResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/exampleFactoryName/datasets/exampleDataset",
  "name": "exampleDataset",
  "properties": {
    "type": "AzureBlob",
    "typeProperties": {
      "folderPath": {
        "value": "@dataset().MyFolderPath",
        "type": "Expression"
      },
      "fileName": {
        "value": "@dataset().MyFileName",
        "type": "Expression"
      },
      "format": {
        "type": "TextFormat"
      }
    },
    "description": "Example description",
    "linkedServiceName": {
      "referenceName": "exampleLinkedService",
      "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
    },
    "parameters": {
      "MyFolderPath": {
        "type": "String"
      },
      "MyFileName": {
        "type": "String"
      }
    }
  },
  "etag": "280320a7-0000-0000-0000-59b9712a0000"
}
```

Or you could get the property in the [Azure Data Factory SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.datafactory.models.dataset.-ctor?view=azure-dotnet). Then you could save names into Microsoft SQL Server.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Is there a way to automatically read the container name and hand it over to an SQL Server table?

Comment: @MichelleTurner Sorry,no such automatically method to hand it. You may need to get the folderName via Dataset.properties in sdk by yourself then store it into sql server table.

Comment: @MichelleTurner Hi, if my answer helps you, you could mark it for others' reference on the forum. Thx.

Comment: @MichelleTurner Hi, if my answer helps you, you could mark it for others' reference on the forum. Thx.